# KeystoneJS: where are callHook hooks defined?

Tags: keystonejs

I want to add logic to the pre:signin and post:signin hooks, but can't find where they are defined. In admin/server/api/session/signin.js, I find the callHook()s for both, but can't find the actual hooks. Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeystoneJS is using [grappling-hook](https://github.com/keystonejs/grappling-hook) . and thats why you can use callHook.

in  node_modules/keystone/index.js  you can see this code

```
var grappling = require('grappling-hook');

grappling.mixin(this).allowHooks('pre:static', 'pre:bodyparser', 'pre:session', 'pre:routes', 'pre:render', 'updates', 'signout', 'signin', 'pre:logger');
```

I am not sure but you are not finding the actual hooks **because they really don't exist**.

The methods are defined in keystone and grapple simply makes them hoockable. e.g **signin is the method defined in keystone instance and grapple made it hoockable.**
And here is the way you will just tell what to do after signing is completed.

```
 keystone.callHook(user, 'post:signin', function (err) {
      if (err) return res.json({ error: 'post:signin error', detail: err });
      res.json({ success: true, user: user });
 });
```

So in layman term you r saying.. Hay keystone, call my function after This user is signed in. and for that there is really no code inside keystone.

MY knowledge is limited here how the user is passed and how it happens that only when this user logged in.  I think, we still need some experts light here.

Comment: Thanks. I got that far, but then don't see any actual hooks anywhere. Can you provide a bit more direction on _where_ they should be created and/or an example of one? For example, if I want to add a post:signin hook, how do I wire up grappling-hook to find the func I create?

Comment: keystone.callHook(newUser, 'post:signin', function (err) {  }

Comment: Ah, so my confusion was--is?--I expected callHook() to call a hook that's defined elsewhere, when in fact it's actually defining and calling the hook function at the same time. The 3rd parameter is the hook function.

Comment: the beauty of node.js is its culture of being blocked on anything. So you will alwase deal with call back,promise etc.  so when you call keystone.callHook(user,'post:signin',my function) that means you are saying. Hay keystone, call my function after This user is signed in. and for that there is really no code  inside keystone. its magic go grapple.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. I was able to hook into sign in/sign out. But what I really would like to is have a post hook run after an item is persisted to a document. My initial guess was to use the updates hook, however my call back is never called when I add or update to a document. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you explored mongoose,  pre and post hook.

Answer (score 0):

I had a use-case that required a function be called every time a specific model was added to the database. I found out that you can use the  [Mongoose middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) specifically the post middleware to achieve such results. So in my case I had a Product schema in which I wanted a function to run everytime a new product was added or updated. It was as easy as adding the following:

```
keystone.lists.Product.schema.post('save',function(){
console.log('called after new item saved');});
```